# Using inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis

> UPDATE: Let $x=(x_{n})$ and $y=(y_{n}) \in A$ with $A:=\{x=(x_{n})\in \ell^{2}| \phantom{x} \|x\|\leq 1\}$. Prove that $d:A\times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ defined by 
>   $$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|$$
>   is bounded.

Let $x,y\in A$ we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}(|x_{n}|+|y_{n}|) \phantom{x} (1) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}|x_{n}|+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}|y_{n}| \phantom{x} (2)\\
&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}} \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|^{2}} + \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}} \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_{n}|^{2}} \phantom{x} (3) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{1-1/3}\right)^{1/2} \|x_{n}\|_{2}+\left(\frac{1}{1-1/3}\right)^{1/2} \|y_{n}\|_{2} \phantom{x} (4)\\
&= \sqrt{3/2} \|x_{n}\|_{2}+\sqrt{3/2} \|y_{n}\|_{2}.\phantom{x} (5)
\end{align*}

Thus, $d(x,y)$ is bounded.

What is used in these steps:
(1) Triangle inequality ?
(2) What is used here?
(3) Cauchy schwarz?
(4) and (5) geometric series and standard calculation.

Comment: You proved that the series defining $d$ is convergent, so aren't you done?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Triangle inequality: $|a-b|=|a+(-b)|\leqslant |a|+|-b|=|a|+|b|$.

(2) Linearity of the summation: the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.

(3) Yes, it's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

(4) and (5) Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much @Davide. I was just about to update my own answer. I still have one question though about the mapping being well defined. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some feedback on that.